# my list view does not on screen, but everything is fine

Tags: android

my code is compile without errors , but I don't see nothing on screen just enough list item what the getCount() return (6 item). I use custom adapter and custom layout. Please help me guys.

Here is my code:

xml list:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="bbeniful.com.listhandle.MainActivity"> 
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>    
</LinearLayout>
```

custom list view xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:weightSum="1">
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/myitemlistPicture"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.37" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/myItemlisttext"
    android:layout_width="150dp"
    android:layout_height="153dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="25sp"
    android:layout_weight="0.64" />

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is my custom adapter:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
Context context;


String[] names;
Integer[] imgId;




public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] names,Integer[] imgId) {
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
    this.imgId = imgId;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return names.length;
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
   }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater =
  (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

        Holder holder = new Holder();
        holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView) 
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.myItemlisttext);
        holder.image = (ImageView)
        convertView.findViewById(R.id.myitemlistPicture);
    }

    return convertView;
    }

    }

  final class Holder{
    TextView txtviewfirstname;
    ImageView image;
  }
```

and last mainactivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
ListView myListview;
Activity context = null;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] name = {

            "asd",
            "asd",
            "asd",
            "asd",
            "asd",
            "asd",
            "asd"


    };
    Integer[] imgId = {

            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon,
            R.drawable.icon
    };


    myListview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.myListView);;
    context = this;
    myListview.setAdapter(new MyAdapter(this,name,imgId));

}
}
```

Comment: You aren't allocating your items. Hint: you aren't using `names` or `imgId` variables in the adapter

Comment: Cause you don't set anything to both `txtviewfirstname` and `image` in the `getView()` method

Comment: Yeah , thank you i understand it , but how can i fix it ?

Comment: When you inflate, just allocate the values from your variables (using the `position`) to the elements in your `convertView`

Answer (score 0):

basically you missed these two lines

```
  holder.txtviewfirstname.setText(names[position]);
  holder.image.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
```

which sets value to `ListView`

i modified your Adapters code, try this

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  Context context;
  String[] names;
  Integer[] imgId;

 public MyAdapter(Context context, String[] names,Integer[] imgId) {
 this.context = context;
 this.names = names;
 this.imgId = imgId; 
  }

  @Override
   public int getCount() {
       return names.length;
   }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
   }

   @Override
   public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
   }

  @Override
   public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

     if (convertView == null) {
       LayoutInflater inflater =
   (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);

    Holder holder = new Holder();
    holder.txtviewfirstname = (TextView) 
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.myItemlisttext);
    holder.image = (ImageView)
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.myitemlistPicture);
}
  holder.txtviewfirstname.setText(names[position]);
  holder.image.setImageResource(imgId[position]);
return convertView;
}

}

  final class Holder{
     TextView txtviewfirstname;
     ImageView image;
   }
```